# Impact of using Daily Time Window for Large Queries

Tags: list-view-threshold

What would be the impact on perfomance if i configure Daily Time Window for Large Queries instead of increasing list view threshold?

Does it mean the same as increasing list view threshold for a specific time period?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, effectively you are telling the system to go ahead, run the query and don't worry about locking tables or response times. It's an appropriate way around not being able to run the queries at all.

I manage the large list SSRS reports this way, where reports don't need to be run in real time and "last nights" position is plenty good enough.